# Lebesgue measurability of $(0,1)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I can show that any interval of the form $(a,\infty)$ is Lebesgue measurable from first principles. Thus $(0,\infty)$ and

$$
(-\infty, 1)=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\left(\infty,1-\frac{1}{k}\right]=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{k},\infty\right)^C
$$

are Lebesgue measurable so that

$$
(0,1)=(-\infty,1)\cap(0,\infty)
$$

is Lebesgue measurable and I'm done.

I was wondering if there is a different/more direct approach to take? For example, could I start directly with the Caratheodory criterion and argue that for any set $A$ that $m^*(A) \ge m^*(A\cap(0,1))+m*(A\cap(0,1)^C)$ ?

I haven't had much luck trying this on my own and I haven't been able to find much looking online so I thought I would open the question to our community.

Comment: The Carathéodory criterion defines measurability of, say, $(0,1)$ by $m^*(A) = m^*(A\cap(0,1))+m*(A\cap(0,1)^C)$ for all $A$. You need $m$ first then comes the rest. The above quoted argumentation does not require the existence of an $m$.

Comment: I argue that $(a,\infty)$ is measurable by showing for any subset $A$ we have $m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap (a,\infty))+m^*(A\cap (a,\infty)^C)$ by working with an open cover of $A$. That is what I meant by first principles. Then I rely on the fact that the measurable sets form a $\sigma-$ algebra for the rest. It just seems like a roundabout answer and I was wondering if there is a more direct way of proving it.

Comment: Ok. Then I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct approach that works because intervals have the nice property that intersection of intervals is an interval (or empty).

If $m^*A = \infty$ then there is nothing to do, so suppose $m^*A < \infty$,
let $\epsilon>0$ and let $I_k$ be a collection of open intervals so that $A \subset \cup_k I_k$ and
$m^*A > \sum_k l(I_k) - {1 \over 2}\epsilon$.

Let $H_k = I_k \cap (0,1)$, $J_k = I_k \cap (-\infty, {1 \over 2^{k+2}} \epsilon)$,
and $L_k = I_k \cap (1-{1 \over 2^{k+2}} \epsilon, \infty)$. All of these are open intervals, and $H_k$ forms a cover of $(0,1) \cap A$ and the $J_k,L_k$ form
an open cover of $(0,1)^c \cap A$.

We see that $l(H_k )+l( J_k ) + l( L_k) \le l(I_k) + {1 \over 2^{k+1} } \epsilon$, so
\begin{eqnarray}
m^*(A \cap (0,1)) + m^* ( A \cap (0,1)^c) &\le &\sum_k l(H_k) + \sum_k (l(J_k)+l(L_k)) \\
&\le & \sum_k l(I_k) + {1 \over 2} \epsilon \\
&\le& m^* A + \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have the desired result.